# How can you merge severals columns in the same dataframe into one, represented in an array form?

Tags: python, pandas

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EWy3.png)
For example:

```
col 1    col 2       col 3

0        2           3

4                    2

-2

3        3           3
```

Expected output

```
col 1

[0,2,3]

[4,2]

[-2]

[3,3,3]
```

Comment: `df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg(list).to_frame('col 1')`

Comment: Almost there! That creates a list of lists and keeps the empty values: [[4,2, ]] instead of [4,2]. How could I get just non empty values and a single list?

Comment: By providing an actual [mcve] so it's clear what data you are working with.  You need to make the "empty" values `NaN` so they are dropped by the `stack`.  If they are empty strings, mask first.